# Debugging iPhone CalDAV interactions?

Tags: iphone, debugging, caldav

I'm trying to connect my internal CalDAV server to my iPhone but am running into issues.  The CalDAV account is recognized as valid on the "Mail, Contacts, Calendars" settings page, and I can see activity on my server where (as far as I can tell) valid XML is being sent to the device, but none of these events are showing up in the Calendar (nor is it displayed as an available CalDAV calendar).

This is a new CalDAV interface, so I'm fairly certain it's an issue on my end - but I can't see what's causing the iPhone to choke.  Is there a way to access debugging output/log files for the iPhone calendar app?  If not, is there a reliable iPhone emulator that runs the Calendar app (the emulators I've come across are geared for custom app dev, not for testing the "standard" apps).